# Competitions / tests for General Physical Preparedness?

Tags: strength, endurance

I am searching for some test or competition, what measures the level of GPP.

**The test should be:**

- complete - it should test absolute strength, relative strength and endurance (maybe more types of endurance)
- easy measurable and repeatable - every healthy person should be able to do it with standard equipment and minimum time of preparation (to learn the test skills safely should not take more than few weeks).
- the test should emphasize balance - it should not be possible to obtain good score with just one skill. Rather the test should cause a bad ranking for everybody with lack in one of the skills.
- all exercises in test should be save and not stupid
- test should be universal (the results should not be directly dependent on bodyweight or height)

**Optionally:**

- it would be great if the test already have long scoreboards across population from amateurs to elites validated by some authority

**Other notes: (edit)**

According to first answer I realized few other points. Keep them in mind:

- Pushups for high reps are endurance test (not the relative strength test)
- Benchpress and situps are not directly related to GPP, thus they are irrelevant

Because of the above points, all military/firemen/... selection tests what I find out have only small value from GPP point of view. Those tests mainly consist only from endurance or irrelevant events.

So far I have found just the **Tactical Strength Challenge** http://www.strongfirst.com/tactical-strength-challenge/

Is there anything else?

Comment: There was at least one similar question somewhere on this site. Lots of cool info & research was in it too since the questioner was looking for additional tests that he didnt already know about.

Answer (score 2):

So you want something universal, with validations, easily measurable and repeatable as well as measuring endurance and strength. Why not just use standard military training fitness tests?

A basic one is the US Army Physical Fitness test, which includes pushups, situps, and a 2-mile run.

http://usmilitary.about.com/od/army/a/afpt.htm

You can also look at some of the US Marine Corps ones, which are slightly different.

If this is not broad enough, or is too simple, there are some VERY GOOD special forces ones that I've used in the past. For example, JTF2 (Canadian Special Forces) has one that encompasses the bench press, pullups, pushups, situps, and a 1.5 mile run, with validated scores and all the fun stuff.

http://www.cg.cfpsa.ca/cg-pc/London/SiteCollectionDocuments/ENGLISH/Fitness/Specialty%20Tests/JTF2%20Pre-Selection%20Physical%20Fitness%20Evaluation.pdf

Comment: The Singapore National fitness test, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Physical_Fitness_Award has been around since beginning of the 1980s

Comment: Military fitness tests are great but you do have to be aware that you should not train for them if you widh to use them as a benchmark. You can get a great score if you only train situps/pushups/1.5mile runs. As with all tests, it is only confirming your ability to do certain things.